# Regex Group Matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a pattern like so:

**Pattern**: (abc)(def)(ghi)h
**Match**:
    Group 0 = [a,b,c]
    Group 1 = [d,e,f]
    Group 2 = [g,h,i]
    Group 3 = h

Is it possible via regex to extrapolate the data into a list like that described?

The code being used is Python for reference.

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: This isn't possible in regex alone, it's capture always returns a number-indexed array of strings, never a complex data structure like that. but it should be trivial in any programming language to convert the results. Like Danial said, what language are you using?

Comment: The trailing h will probably need parens around it as well, but of cource, as everyone else is saying, we need to know what language you're using.

Comment: I am using python, my first thought was kind of hackish, but would work.  Strip the ('s and convert the )'s into spaces then just do a string split on the spaces.  Was hoping to use regex or something nicer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, that's not possible in one regex. You could do something like this:

```
import re

matches = re.findall('[^()]+', '(abc)(def)(ghi)h')
map = []
for m in matches: 
  map.append(list(m))
for e in map:
  print e
```

which will print:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
['g', 'h', 'i']
['h']
```

### EDIT

The pattern `[^()]` matches any character other than a `(` and `)`, so `[^()]+` matches one or more characters other than `(` and `)`.

Everything between a `[` and `]` is called a character class, and will always match just a single character. The `^` at the start makes it a negated character class (matches *everything-but* what is defined in it).

More info about character classes: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: This works for what I need, I'm trying to understand the pattern though. IIRC '[]' signifies a grouping then you look for where a group starts with a '(', then that's where I'm lost.  Shouldn't it be ^(.*)?  I'm not sure how that pattern works, could you possibly explain it? Is there a way to signify for example that the '(abc)' was encased in parenthesis and the 'h' was not?  Is there a way to make it only pick up what is encased in parenthesis?